# 3rd party softwares fonts being pixelated on UHD display

Tags: windows-10, fonts, resolution

I just got a Dell XPS 15 with UHD display.

The display looks very nice and is perfectly sharp. However, some fonts in 3rd party software seem pixelated. For example, *Steam*:

[image]

If you compare the left side to the right side you see a big difference.

Is there a way I can change this? The system resolution is **3840 x 2160**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens if you have a screen with a high resolution and you put the DPI scaling to at least 125% to make everything easier to read.
Windows 10 is using a new scaling method for DPI that causes the fuzzy/pixelated text problem.

A product called [XPExplorer – Windows 10 DPI Fix](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/) may be able to fix the
problem by resetting the DPI algorithm to what it was in Windows 8.1.
I admit that I do not know if it still works in the latest version of Windows 10.

Start it up and check *Use Windows 8.1 DPI Scaling (our fix)* and then choose your scaling level.

[image]

A restart is required to complete the installation.

The installation of this product is necessary, rather than a 'Registry Tweak',
because Windows will reset your dpi settings every 2 reboots. Which means that you would have to adjust the registry again and again. This product does it for you on every reboot.